# images does not appear in html, it is apearing like it is broken

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Notice: when i go to [http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/download.jpeg] it takes me to the home page while the url is [http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/download.jpeg].

images not apearing in html, se the code down there, please tell me what is the problem.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class jop(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import jop
```

## Create your views here.

```
def home(request):
    jops = jop.objects
    return render(request, 'jops/home.html', {'jops':jops},)
```

home.html

```
 <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        {% for jop in jops.all %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <img src="{{jop.image.url}}"/>
            <p class="card-text">{{ jop.summary }}</p>
          </div>
       </div>
      </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
  </div>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

import jops.views

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('', jops.views.home, name='home'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Your empty reguar expression in the url mapping will match everything.

Comment: what do u see when you inspect img source in browser and is your field name image.url  in model class

Comment: thanks Klaus D can you help, i do not get you right, please write in code so i can understand xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to anchor and terminate your regex for the home page, otherwise it will match everything including your image URL.

```
url('^$', jops.views.home, name='home'),
```

Alternatively, use the new path syntax:

```
path('', jops.views.home, name='home'),
```